# Place digits in parentheses that are not negative

Tags: regex, r

I am attempting to place all digits in parentheses that do not contain a negative value, but using a word boundary does not seem to work.

```
x <- '125 -110 55 25 135 -145 10 -199'
gsub('\\b(\\d+)', '(\\1)', x)
```

The above places all numbers in parentheses, the word boundary seems to match the negative numbers as well. How can I fix this?

Only `125`, `55`, `25`, `135`, `10` should each be placed in parentheses.

Comment: Try using `'[^-](\\d+)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the hyphen is being considered as a boundary. You need a *Negative Lookbehind* here.

```
x <- '125 -110 55 25 135 -145 10 -199'
gsub('(?<![\\d-])(\\d+)', '(\\1)', x, perl=T)

# [1] "(125) -110 (55) (25) (135) -145 (10) -199"
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<!         # look behind to see if there is not:
  [\d-]      #   any character of: digits (0-9), '-'
)            # end of look-behind
```

Answer (score 2):

**So `\b` Doesn't Work? Make Your Own Boundary!**

Use this:

```
grepl("(?<![-\\d])\\d\\d*", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG7gB2).

The regex (without escaping) is `(?<![-\d])\d\d*`

**Explanation**

- The negative lookbehind `(?<![-\d])` asserts that what precedes is not a hyphen or a digit. In essence, this is your DIY boundary. :)
- `\d` matches the first digit
- `\d*` matches any trailing digits

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit`, because I have to

```
> s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
> s[!grepl("\\-", s)] <- paste0("(", s[!grepl("\\-", s)], ")")  
> paste(s, collapse = " ")
# [1] "(125) -110 (55) (25) (135) -145 (10) -199"
```